# Simple blank activity cause memory leak. Why?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

Just for the test I've created two activities

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bpm);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                Intent intent = new Intent(TestActivity.this, TestActivity2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class TestActivity2 extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                Intent intent = new Intent(TestActivity2.this, TestActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Then I just pressing on the home button frequently to switch between them and that what I see in the LogCat:

```
05-02 15:55:36.211: D/dalvikvm(15615): GC_CONCURRENT freed 116K, 4% free 7548K/7812K, paused 4ms+2ms, total 20ms
05-02 15:55:40.301: D/dalvikvm(15615): GC_CONCURRENT freed 79K, 3% free 7853K/8080K, paused 2ms+2ms, total 24ms
05-02 15:55:43.611: D/dalvikvm(15615): GC_CONCURRENT freed 97K, 3% free 8189K/8432K, paused 1ms+10ms, total 53ms
05-02 15:55:50.171: D/dalvikvm(15615): GC_CONCURRENT freed 93K, 3% free 8492K/8732K, paused 5ms+9ms, total 44ms
05-02 15:55:53.021: D/dalvikvm(15615): GC_CONCURRENT freed 93K, 3% free 8788K/9028K, paused 2ms+5ms, total 35ms
05-02 15:55:54.861: D/dalvikvm(15615): GC_CONCURRENT freed 96K, 3% free 9116K/9360K, paused 2ms+9ms, total 48ms
05-02 15:55:57.061: D/dalvikvm(15615): GC_CONCURRENT freed 116K, 3% free 9504K/9768K, paused 2ms+7ms, total 45ms
```

You can see that used memory grows up. So I have a question: How is this even possible???
Please, explain if anyone have a clue.

Comment: Stay calm! its not a memory leak  :)

Comment: "Share state between activities": The right way depends on whether it'll be for the following activities or for the whole app. In the first case, if it's not much data, passing `Intent` extras makes sense (also because of the recosntruction mechanisms Android uses), in the latter (as with a secure server connection) you'll subclass `Application` and maintain references there, becuase that object lives as long as the hosting process. But I'm not sure you really want this endless stack of A,B,A etc in a real product. At least not without additional flags telling Android what you mean by it.

Comment: Just for example: I store a number in SharedPrefs, I can change it in my activity and I assume to see changes in all activities in history. The right way to reach that will be to update UI every onResume, am I right?

Comment: `onResume` is definitely a good place to check for app state changes which are out of direct control of an Activity. But SharedPreferences involve XML file processing in the background. Unless you need this level of persistency even between two activities, I wouldn't necessarily use it for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no evidence for a "memory leak" here.

A memory leak would be a situation where memory can not be freed. From the few figures you present, this cannot be concluded; also the code does not suggest that you're creating a memory leak.

It's up to Android, however, to decide when exactly it physically deletes Activity objects which are no longer visible; after all, there's the back key and it's more efficient to have the old Activity still in memory upon returning to it.

Android sees the Activity instances as different because it cannot make assumtions about their internal state. So you're creating a growing history list of visited `Activity` objects. When Android deletes an old one from memory, it saves its `Intent` and any InstanceState `Bundle` information.

The fact that the figures differ is also owed to the garbage collector's policies. After all, your `Activity` objects aren't the only objects created along the way; a couple of user interface objects are created as well, and the garbage collector needs not always free all memory just because it's running. It may as well decide that it has freed enough memory and leave some stuff for the next round.

Comment: I see. I'll extend my question then. Is it possible to share internal state between activities? Just to make sure that all the activities in the history are up to date accordingly to latest changes I made in the activity on the top.

Answer (score 0):

It is because when you run new activity previous is not destroyed and it keep using memory. You can return to it by pressing back key.

Comment: The following quote: "when you run new activity previous is not destroyed and it keep using memory" is not a valid statement in general.

Comment: Not saying it in general. I meant the case author described.

Comment: Even in the case the author describes, it's not true in general.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a memory leak here. The Concurrent GC running is not evidence of a memory leak, as it may decide to not collect all inactive objects.

You can try calling the GC explicitly with `System.gc()`, which will (usually) force the garbage collector to run and collect all expired objects.

In your case, try calling `System.gc()` in the `onCreate()` method, and see if the App's memory continues to grow. That way, you can tell for sure if your code is leaking memory.

Comment: I'd like to say that explicitly calling the garbage collector on an Android system is usually not a smart idea, because Android has a very smart GC strategy.

Comment: Agreed. Don't do this in production code! Calling the GC explicitly is only for testing for memory leaks and such.

Comment: You're right, it can be useful during development/testing, and should be avoided in production code.

Answer (score 0):

Let call TestActivity A and TestActivity2 B,  then when start B from A the first time in the stack you have
A --> B. When you start A from B the stack will be A --> B --> A and then A --> B --> A --> B. So you can see the stack is growing.
Try going back and forth a few time and then press the back key, it will take a quite a few number of back key presses before you get the Home screen.

Comment: I beg your pardon but have you actually tried this? Because, yes, the "stack is growing", but whether or not the activities stay in memory depends on the available memory.